# Is there a way to use "length" or "left" attribute on a port from instantiated component in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

Is there any way to declare a signal size based on a port from instantiated component?

```
.....

signal newSignal : std_logic_vector(work.SyncVec.sig_i'left downto 0);  --something like that

begin

   -- Synchronize all inputs
   u_InputSyncs : entity work.SyncVec
      port map (
         clk_i => sysClk100M,
         rst_i => sysRst100M,
         sig_i => inputs,
         sig_o => inputsSync
      );

.....
```

Vivado returns error for:

> signal newSignal : std_logic_vector(work.SyncVec.sig_i'left downto 0);
>   --something like that

```
ERROR: [VRFC 10-1266] prefix of expanded name does not denote an enclosing construct
```

Many thanks

Comment: What happens when you try it?  You provide neither valid code nor a [mcve]. Note that if the port association actual `inputs` were declared prior to `newSignal` it could be evaluated directly in the declaration of `newSignal`.  The prefix `SyncVec` of the selected wouldn't be visible without a use clause. IEEE Std 1076-2008 3.2.2 Entity header "In certain circumstances, the names of generics and ports declared in the entity header become visible outside of the design entity (see 12.2 and 12.3)."  (Scope of declarations, Visibility, 12.4 Use clauses).

Comment: `error: no declaration for "syncvec"`. Add a use clause `use work.all;` prior to the `newSignal` declaration and `error: no declaration for "inputs" in entity "syncvec". Instead, `signal newSignal: std_logic_vector(inputs'left downto 0);` with `inputs` previously declared will analyze. Where `signal newSignal: std_logic_vector(work.SyncVec.sig_i'left downto 0);` produces `error: an expanded name is only allowed within the construct`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv37P.jpg

Comment: Changed from `SyncVec.inputs'left` to `work.SyncVec.sig_i'left` and added Vivado error output. Does anyone have an idea if that's even supported in VHDL?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but in the example you provided, you could presumably use `std_logic_vector(inputs'range)`. More generally, I'm not sure that what you want to do would be a great idea. If the bitwidth of `sig_i` can be changed at compile time, then this should be done using a generic (or a constant stored in a package). Either way, this value will be clearly visible to you in the level above in the hierarchy. Trying to do the same thing with attributes seems less clear and more difficult to manage.

Comment: You run into the same basic issue, your readers don't have enough information. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to explore alternatives. Otherwise the answer to your question is No.

Comment: *Changed from SyncVec.inputs'left to work.SyncVec.sig_i'left and added Vivado error output. Does anyone have an idea if that's even supported in VHDL?* This is the same error reported above by a different implementation - *error: an expanded name is only allowed within the construct*. The declaration of the port is not found immediately within the region (the entity declaration) see 12.3 Visibility paragraph 5 "...at the place of the suffix of an expanded name whose prefix denotes the construct...", it's found within the formal port clause (3.2.2 Entity header) which isn't named.